# Add a logo to MATLAB figure

Tags: matlab

I have read many articles on adding an image as the background for a figure in MATLAB but I want to know if it is possible to add a logo to a MATLAB figure e.g at the top right or left hand side.

Comment: So did any solution suggested solved your problem?

Comment: Not exactly, I decided to insert axis into my figure and then insert the picture. However after saying that, your answer was the better of the two given and I will accept it since it is a possibility. Thanks!

Comment: ok sure no problem thanks for that! I was curious as to how you solved your problem; it was an interesting question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is alternative solution using subplot. It might not be the most versatile/robust but it could solve your problem:

```
clc;
clear all;

LogoImage = imread('Matlab_logo.png');

x=0:0.1:10;
y=sin(x);

figure

subplot('Position',[0.8 0.8 0.2 0.2]) % Place the logo using the sub^plot command.
imshow(LogoImage)

%set(gca,'LooseInset',get(gca,'TightInset')) % Not necessary... actually it can be used to get rid of the blank space around plots. In this case it does not apply however.

subplot(1,5,1:4) % Make the actual plot span 4 of the 5 subplots.
plot(x,y)
```

Giving this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
>> z = peaks; z = round(255 * z/max(max(z)));
>> x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 101);
>> plot(x, sin(x))
>> hold on
>> image([4,2*pi], [0.5,1.5], z)
>> xlim([0, 2*pi])
>> ylim([-1.5, 1.5])
```

which results in the following plot

[image]

Comment: What if I wanted to put the logo outside the graph?